# Inserting variable as SQL value in python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```
exp = "Ted is a good film"
cursor.execute ("insert into films (descp) values (exp)")
cursor.commit()
```

I'm using above code with MS SQL server, but it says: Invalid column name'exp'
I'm using pyodbc.

Comment: FWIW, any of the solutions would work, but (at present) xbb's is the only one which isn't potentially vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Aya why you think that I'm using this for sql injection ?

Answer (score 10):

```
cursor.execute ("insert into films (descp) values (?)",exp)
```

Comment: My solution works, but xbb is more correct solution. [Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#execute)

Comment: Your solution is worked, but it says : The statement has been terminated

Answer (score 3):

I think you should pass it as a tuple:

```
cursor.execute ("insert into films (descp) values (?)", (exp,))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need introduce `exp` content into insert expression as string. You can use [string format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) and ' ':

```
exp = "Ted is a good film"
cursor.execute ("insert into films (descp) values ('{exp}')".format(exp=exp))
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: After trying it said : The statement has been terminated.

Comment: How about `exp = "anything'); drop table films; --"` ?